# object key is not defined javascript/ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects, ejs

I have an array called posts and it contains an object:

```
var posts = []

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        homestct: homeStartingContent,
        posts: posts
    })
})

app.post('/compose', function(req, res) {
    const comp = {
        title: req.body.compTitle,
        post: req.body.compPost
    }
    posts.push(comp)
    res.redirect('/')

})
```

and when I try to retrieve the key: title in home.ejs =

```
    <% for (var i = 0; i <= posts.length; i++) { %>
        <% console.log(posts[i].title) %>
            <% } %>
```

it gives me thee error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Please help T_T

Answer (score 2):

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
```

`i` should be less than `posts.length`. Replace `<=` with `<`.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that you have `<=` instead of `<`. Let me illustrate why.

Let's assume your posts array looks like this:

```
[
  { title: 'A', post: 'a' }, // This will be posts[0]
  { title: 'B', post: 'b' }  // This will be posts[1]
]
```

You have two posts, so `posts.length` will be `2`. The first post is `posts[0]`, the second post is `posts[1]`.

Since you do `for (var i = 0; i <= posts.length; i++)`, it means your loop will stop only when `i <= posts.length` is no longer true, meaning if `i <= 2` is no longer true, i.e. when `i` reaches `3`, the loop will stop, but it will be executed for `0`, `1` and `2`.

You may notice that now this means *three* indexes are accessed (`0`, `1` and `2`) despite your array having only *two* posts inside (with indexes `0` and `1`)!

In the third iteration you are accessing `posts[2]` which is `undefined`. This means that the attempt to read `posts[2].title` fails because it essentially tries to read `undefined.title` which isn't possible, hence the error `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

Bottom line: When you have a zero-based index (starting with `0`) and you have the total number of elements as limiter (from `.length` for instance), you always need to use `<` and not `<=` to ensure that you are stopping one index short of the length, since the last index will always be `length - 1`.

Suggestion: Instead of messing around with the index, you could iterate over the elements themselves, using [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
    <% for (const post of posts) { %>
        <% console.log(post.title) %>
    <% } %>
```